# ASP.NET web application takes 3 hrs to get build and publish

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a web application written in year **2008 in asp.net 2.0 (VB language)**. we have upgraded the application in between around in year 2014 to **.net 4.0**, our application grows insanly in previous years and now there are around **3000 pages in the application**.

We always require to publish the whole application to update any hotfix to production and the publish process of application took around **3 hrs** to complete.

I need your help to understand how can I improve this process and reduce the time of hotfix update on production Or if there any mechanism through which I could break my application in small peaces.

*My publish profile*
[image]

*Configuration Option*

[image]

Comment: Do you run the build with multiple threads or single threaded? It's the switch /m on msbuild invocation

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, are you pre-compiling your web application?

Comment: Use web deploy, deploys only updated files, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy

Comment: I use standard Publish webapp option of visual studio. Screen added on question

Comment: We have on premises customer of our application and to send update for them we have to send them dll patched , we can not connect their server directly from our Visual studio

Comment: "Delete all files during publish" should't be a problem, I mean that is used when you save some temp files under your app and your disk space is a problem, anyway try without that, maybe your app is truly huge. Can you give us a size of your app? and one more thing can you click on "configure" then give us a print with that.

Comment: Then is not your problem, is their  problem, bet FTP is used.

Comment: worth turning pre-compilation off and seeing what the difference is. Of course this implies your pages will be compiled on first load, and users will be affected by that.

Comment: @SilentTremor  , the maximum time take for the App_Code folder ,, configuration screen is attched

Comment: Also - I have heard of mspmng.exe (i.e. Security Essentials) slowing down pre-compilation significantly.  Is it installed on your build server?

Answer (score 0):

You have selected the option "Create a separate assembly for each page and control", this means that you are going to create at least 3000 dll file (1 for each page, excluding user control). Matthew Evans is right, windows defender don't like new assemblies to be created unders it's nose, and it analyzed all those files to be sure that they doesn't contains viruses.
My advise is to try the "Merge all output to a single file" option and to temporary disable the antivirus (or even better add you project path to the exclusion list)

Do you have a lot of resources files (like images and css) ? This can also be a problem if you don't have an SSD because copying thousand of files on a standard HDD can be a very time consuming operation. Also, keep in mind that you have to copy at least one DLL per page and also one aspx file for page...